# RSpec's post and get methods fail to recognize non-existing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm doing *request* specs for a JSON REST API using a BDD approach. This means specs will fail by default, since nothing is really implemented, including routes. Here's a simple example:

```
  describe 'POST /users' do
    context 'when the request is valid' do
      before { post "/users", params: {userName: 'johndoe22'}}

      it 'creates and returns the user' do
        expect(json['userName']).to eq('johndoe22')
      end

      it 'returns status code 201 (created)' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
      end
    end
    ...
  end
```

Basically I request something (either using *get* or *post*), then I parse the response as JSON. The problem is, if */users* does not exist, instead of getting an *ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches* error, *post* fails silently and then the spec fails when I try to parse the response as JSON. This response actually contains the *no route matches* error.

In other words, instead of failing right when the *post* method is called, the test fails later when I try to parse the response (a regular HTML page which cannot be parsed to JSON).

```
Failure/Error: JSON.parse(response.body)

 JSON::ParserError:
   784: unexpected token at '<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   ...
```

For reference, I'm loosely following this tutorial: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-one. As you can see, he gets the appropriate error when doing request specs.

Why is this happening? Am I missing some sort of configuration?

Comment: I don't see the problem, the spec shouldn't fail on the request since that's not an expectation, it fails on the parser and that's ok. You could add a spec checking that the resposne code is not 500 nor 404 if you wan't to test that the route does not fail.

Comment: @arieljuod I see what you mean. I guess I don't really understand why that doesn't happen in the tutorial (RSpec version, maybe?). A _No route matches_ error is clearer than what I'm getting (which is crazy verbose, because it outputs the whole content of the HTML page, which I cut short in my question). I already have specs that check HTTP status codes, and with no routes they obviously fail but it's not clear why. Failing right when the request is made looks like a clean way of handling it (i.e. in the _post_ method). Can I make that happen somehow?

Comment: the html you are receiving is html for the error page. are you setting the spec as a request spec? Anyway, there's an specific type of spec to test "no route matches" errors, routing specs https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/routing-specs

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see the expected

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches
```

it is most probably because some route **actually matches** that path.

Maybe you have a wildcard or something else in your routes. You can check it out in the console like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/users', method: 'POST')
```

Comment: That's the thing, though. If I remove all routing configuration on /users and I run the line of code you provided, I get the expected "No route matches", but when I run the specs I don't get the error. As I said, the response I try to parse as JSON in my spec, does contain the error somewhere in the body, but RSpec does not recognize it and thus fails later when I attempt to parse the response.

Comment: What if you put this `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/users', method: 'POST')` in your rspec expectations? Also how about this `expect(response).to have_http_status(201)` expectation - does it fail or pass?

Comment: I can try your first approach; and I already have specs for HTTP status codes: they fail but that can mean different things, as I understand. I feel like something's not right, there are a lot of questions in SO about _No route matches_ in their specs, and they seem to get the error out of the box. Thank you for your time!

Comment: NP. I would try to reproduce it on a clean rails. If not reproducible - keep adding changes one by one until you hit the issue you have here.